# what is the javascript equivalent function for vbscript Mid function? is that substring() or substr()?

Tags: javascript

There are two javascript solutions for this,

```
1. String.substring(from,to) 
2. String.substr(from,length)
```

what is the most convenient solution for vb script Mid() function

Comment: Well what parameters does `Mid` take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `substr` matches the usage of VB `Mid` function closest. The obvious difference is the the VB function *takes a string* as an argument, where the JS `substr` is a *method of the string object*.

```
string.substr(start,length)
```

Comment: [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is the standard version of `substr` (which is semi-standard).

Comment: A bit late with the correction @katspaugh but I think the URL you wanted was this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: And yes, `String.substr()` is deprecated and not part of the ECMAScript standard. If you undeleted your answer and made it standalone (rather than a response to these other answers) I'd vote it up.

Comment: Undeleted, thanks @miken32!

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = "Hello World!".substr(2, 4);
```

is the same as

```
foo = Mid("Hello World!", 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do. If in VBScript you were subtracting to find the length, `substring` may be the most convenient for you since you don't have to calculate the length. If, on the other hand, you have the length and would otherwise need to calculate the end position, `substr` will be more convenient for you.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of mid function is follow,

```
 Mid(string,start[,length])
```

Mid function use length as a parameter.So, you have to use length.

```
 string.substr(start,length)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is deprecated, you should use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) instead.

```
var str = 'hello';
str.slice(2, 4); // ll
```